# rake db:migrate error wrong number of arguments (5 for 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

This is my migration file:

```
class AddSeoMetaInfoToArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :articles, :seo_title, :string, { :default => "", :null => false }
    add_column :articles, :seo_description, :string, { :default => "", :null => false }
    add_column :articles, :seo_keywords, :string, :string, { :default => "", :null => false }
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :articles, :seo_keywords
    remove_column :articles, :seo_description
    remove_column :articles, :seo_title
  end
end
```

When I try to run 'rake db:migrate' I get the following error

```
$ rake db:migrate
AddSeoMetaInfoToArticles: migrating =======================================
-- add_column(:articles, :seo_title, :string, {:default=>"", :null=>false})
   -> 0.0341s
-- add_column(:articles, :seo_description, :string, {:default=>"", :null=>false})
   -> 0.0100s
-- add_column(:articles, :seo_keywords, :string, :string, {:default=>"", :null=>false})
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

wrong number of arguments (5 for 4)

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I'm relatively new to rails and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  This is Rails 3.0.9, and a Postgres db if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add_column :articles, :seo_keywords, :string, :string, { :default => "", :null => false }
```

has `:string` twice, so you end up with 5 arguments being passed instead of 4.

You might also want to consider writing you migration with `change` - your migration is equivalent to

```
class AddSeoMetaInfoToArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table :articles do |t|
      t.string :seo_title, :default => "", :null => false
      t.string :seo_description, :default => "", :null => false
      t.string :seo_keywords, :default => "", :null => false
    end
  end
end
```

which I find easier on the eye. It also has the advantage that you can pass :bulk => true to `change_table` which will combine all 3 column additions into 1 alter table statement, which is usually much faster.

Both ways will of course work.

Comment: /facepalm sometimes you just need another pair of eyes to check it.

Answer (score 0):

You give the `:string` argument twice in this line:

```
    add_column :articles, :seo_keywords, :string, :string, { :default => "", :null => false }
```